# Change SSIS package location (REPOST from SO)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, business-intelligence

My SSIS Package are located in shared drive with a long path name. To make the packages easier and not to remember long path name, I use "Map my network drive" option and use X: drive as an alias to access packages. Next thing I know that all my packages locations have been updated as "X:\Package5.dtsx". Now if the pseudo network drive is disconnect, I cannot access the packages (outside the server).

Please find the snapshot that will justify what I actually meant.

[image]

How can I change the package name from X:\ to actual share drive name (where my package are stored)? I don't want to do some changes that could effect how this package run since they are very critical to the business continuity

Comment: please don't repost from [so], simply "flag" your original question to have it moved here.

Comment: Did that @MaxVernon

Comment: You're just trying to fix paths now, but still check BIDS helper for it's deployment and other helpful tools/automation including fixing relative paths on configurations. http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/ Worst case you could re-deploy your packages with it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you point the 'full path' to the UNC path i.e. `\\<servername>\<sharename>\<directoryname>\<packagename>` instead and see if that works?

Just like when you map the "X" drive to `\\<servername>\<sharename>` just use that in the full path of one of your packages and run to see if it'll work.

If one of your jobs work like that (assuming most all are setup the same and this way, etc), you can probably script out the SQL Agent jobs through SSMS by pressing F7 (once SQL Agent jobs is highlighted), selecting them all from the right pane window, right click, then create to new query window, then do a mass CTRL+H and do a find and replace to replace `X:\` with `\\<servername>\<sharename>`, and then run that.

Just be sure the SSIS proxy account or the SQL Server Agent account has appropriate NTFS and SHARE permissions where the SSIS packages reside to read them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but Please explain what do you mean by first statement?

Comment: @RomilN You will need to reword your request or it's going to be closed. instead of mapping a drive "X" to \\server\share\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\~and so on, you should setup a SHARE at the same level you map the X:\Drive to folder wise, and then put \\servername\newsharename\packagename.dtsx in there perhaps.  Otherwise, you may want to consider putting the SSIS packages on a new location server share wise with a shorter path and point your packages to it one by one perhaps.  I didn't think services could access mapped network drives so I'm a little confused how your packages run too